# Issue with OnClick event on list view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get perform onclick event on list view. If I click on any list item i need the alert as it's respective value. Is this possible? This is my code,

```
  $("#select-choice").on('change', function(event) {


     $("#locationList").empty();
      var catg = this.value;
      var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
      db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '"+catg+"';", [], function (tx, res) {
     var optionheading = '<li value="Select Location">Select Location</li>';
                           $("#locationList").append(optionheading);
                           for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                           var opt  = '<li value="';
                           opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                           opt += '">';
                           opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                           opt += '</li>';
                           $("#locationList").append(opt);
                           }
                           $("#locationList").listview('refresh');
                           });
                           });
                           });
```

I am trying with code as follows but it does not working. Any suggestions please,

```
 $('#locationList > li').click(function(e){
       alert($(this).attr('value'));
        });
```

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="locationList" name="locationList" data-inset="true">
   <li value="Select Location">Select Location</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#locationList > li').click(function(e){
 alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQEUx/1/)

Comment: Your code is working fine. But In my code my control does not go to on click function, In my application I am getting the list view values dynamically. I will update my question can you please tell what did I do wrong

Comment: You need to assign the event again after you added DOM elements on runtime.

Comment: @user3300593: Just bind the event handler like you did previously, using event delegation.

Comment: So you want me to use event delegation?

Comment: @user3300593: Yes. That's what you did before. `$(document).on('click','#locationList li',function(){`. If you don't know what that actually is: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: @user3300593: You should still use `data-value` though.

Comment: @FelixKling is right and I prefer his solution; while mine is the "straight" answer to the question, his way is the semantically correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

`value` is not a valid attribute for `li` elements, hence `this.value` won't work either.

I'd suggest to use `data-*` attribute:

```
<li data-value="A">a</li>
```

then you can get the value with:

```
$(this).data('value')
// or
$(this).attr('data-value')
```

Comment: I tried the same but not even my control does not go the on click function.

Comment: I don't know why you changed your example, but it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Dv6GN/1/

Comment: You did use `data-value` instead of `value`, right?